# How to print Fibonacci series between two integers?

Tags: java, eclipse

I did Fibonacci series method like;

```
public static int fibonacci(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if (n == 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
        }
    }
```

But I need to print this series between two numbers, so I wrote some codes like :

```
int q=0;

while(q<max){

if(fibonacci(q)<min){}

if(fibonacci(q)>max){break;}

if(fibonacci(q)<=max&&fibonacci(q)>=min)                            
System.out.print(fibonacci(q)+" ");                     
q++;
```

this loop in main method. I need to do this in one method, I mean both functions will be in the same method.

Comment: Note that this method is hugely inefficient.

Comment: Oh and by the way, you dont have to check if n==0

Comment: Just check if n<2 return n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number `N` is a fibonacci number, if either `(5*N^2+4)` or `(5*N^2-4)` is a perfect square. I guess you can use this property to print all fibonacci number between `min` and `max`.

For example, `5` is a fibonacci number, and 5 * 5 * 5 - 4 = 121 is a perfect square.

```
for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    if (isPerfectSquare(5*i*i + 4) || isPerfectSquare(5*i*i - 4)) {
        // i is fibonacci number
    } 
}
```

In the above solution, once you get the first two fibonacci numbers, you can skip the loop, and use the fibonacci formula to get the rest of the numbers.

Comment: I need to print fibonacci numbers between two numbers such as;
Enter MAX: 100
Enter MIN: 1

Result: 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89

Comment: @OzanKÖYÜK And that is what I've suggested the solution for. Iterate from `min` to `max`, and whatever number satisfies the above condition is the fibonacci number

Comment: Yes!!. Thank you so much man. Thats what Im looking for.

Comment: that seems to work but you need to make sure to print 1 two times when min is 1

Comment: yea. i need to print "1" by myself if user enter min=1.

Comment: and easy way in this function is to do that is: after the if condition do this if: `if(i==1) i--;`

Comment: This is inneficient when using big numbers because you are going on a for for all numbers and when min is 1 and max is 2147483647 your code will take 30 seconds to compute. If you calculate the fibonacci number you will remove a lot of options like i do in my answer :P my answer takes 1-2 ms to compute that ammount.

Comment: @PedroSilva Did you read my last line? The loop can be skipped as you found first two fibonacci  numbers, and calculate the entire series thereon using the formula.

Comment: @Rohit Jain so if the two first are at 200000 it will take 30 seconds to get there, using it calculating the formula from the beginning is much better :P

Comment: @PedroSilva Seriously, 30 seconds? I hope you understand that's seconds, not milliseconds. A lot can be done in 30 seconds. Have you even benchmarked the solution, before guessing any random time frame.

Comment: @PedroSilva And let's stop comparing performance here. IMO this question was not even about efficient algorithm. It was about a way to get result. There are many ways. You can use the mundane way, going through all fibonacci number from the beginning, or use some mathematical formula that has already been derived to know whether a number is fibonacci or not.

Answer (score 2):

why dont you replace 1 in your first code with the lower one and n with max. it would print the fibonacci series between the two numbers

Try the following

```
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) { 
    int res=fibonacci(i,2); 
    System.out.print(" "+res); 
} 

public static int fibonacci(int n,int m) { 
if (n == 0) { 
    return 0; 
} else if (n == m || n==1) { 
    return 1; 
} else { 
    return fibonacci((n - 1),m) + fibonacci((n - 2),m); 
} 
}
```

Here I am printing between 2 & 5

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

so this is what you want (this function is not optimized, see the next one):

```
public static int fibonacciBetweeen(int min, int max) {
    //get the fibonacci number before the min and the one before that.
    n = 0;
    while(fibonacci(n) < min){
        n++;
    }
    while(fibonacci(n) <= max){
        System.out.print(fibonacci(n)+" ");
        n++;
    }
}
```

use it with your function, it is working but not optimized, i will try to optimize it if you need to.

so calling `fibonacciBetweeen(34, 144);` returns `34 55 89 144`.

**optimized** tested and working, much less time than the previous one

```
public static void fibonacciBetweeen(int min, int max) {
    int n1 = 1, n2=1, aux=0;
    while((aux=n1+n2) < min){
        n1=n2;
        n2=aux;
    }
    while( (aux=n1+n2) <= max){
        System.out.print(aux+" ");
        n1=n2;
        n2=aux;
    }
}
```

Also it takes 700x less time than Rohit Jain answer when max is a very big number like(100000000);

**big numbers test:**

```
fibonacciBetweeen(34, 2147483647);
```

**result:**

```
34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765 10946 17711 28657 46368 75025 121393 196418 317811 514229 832040 1346269 2178309 3524578 5702887 9227465 14930352 24157817 39088169 63245986 102334155 165580141 267914296 433494437 701408733 1134903170 1836311903
```

Took 1 ms

Comment: Can you explain a bit more understandable or can you give an example of your code?

Comment: Is that what you want?

Comment: I need to print fibonacci numbers between two numbers such as;
Enter MAX: 100
Enter MIN: 1
Result: 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89
Its not what im looking for

Comment: Oh i see, ok i will lunch and think about it

Comment: i added a function that do what you pretend.

Comment: optimized run 2000x faster when min is 34 and max is 100000000

Comment: Have you tried the code? Tell something if it does what you pretend.